# grouping NSMutableArray by date xcode

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a `NSMutableArray` of items which contain `itemName` and `eventDate`.

I have sorted the array by date successfully but I would also like to group the items by date so they display as sections in a table.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *items;
```

...

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"eventDate" ascending: TRUE];
return [self.items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting table sections by NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793654/sorting-table-sections-by-nsdate)

Comment: @Amy have you got your answer?

Comment: @Mrunal No I didnt get the answer I need, however I've decided I'm getting ahead of myself by trying to implement things I don't full understand so I'm going back to the documentation and tutorials. Even with the example code in the answers below I couldn't get it to work so it was time to go back to the drawing board. Thanks all for input, not sure what down votes were for as I thought this was a sensible question but then that's just probably more I don't understand yet!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *dateSD= [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"eventDate" ascending: YES];

NSMutableArray *sortedByDate= [UnsortedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: dateSD];
NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[sortedByDate count]];

while([sortedByDate count]) 
{
        id groupLead = [sortedByDate objectAtIndex:0];  
        NSPredicate *itemNamePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@",itemName]; // use itemName as string here

        NSArray *item= [sortedByDate filteredArrayUsingPredicate: itemNamePredicate];

        [sortedArray addObjectsFromArray: item];
        [sortedByDate removeObjectsInArray: item];
}
```

Now check `sortedArray`

Please update variable and property name as per your code. Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't you want to create an array-of-array's, so that it's easy to populate the tableview?

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide the date increments for your table view, i.e. would each section represent items within the same second, hour, day e.t.c.

Assuming you decide on day you could go about it like this:

```
// We will need a date formatter for later
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];   
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

// 1) Get the oldest and newest items
NSDate *oldest = [(Item *)items.firstObject eventDate];
NSDate *newest = [(Item *)items.lastObject eventDate];

// 2) Get an array with the relevant dates in it...
NSTimeInterval timeDiffSecs = [newest timeIntervalSinceDate:oldest];
int days = (((timeDiffSecs / 60) / 60) / 24) + 1;
NSMutableArray *dates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < days; i++) {
    [dates addObject:[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:((24 * 60) *60) * i since date:oldest]];
}
```

Then using this data you need to implement the following `UITableView` data source methods:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // This is the date that you will group the items under
    NSDate *sectionDate = dates[indexPath.section];
    NSArray *filteredItems = [items filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"eventDate >= %@ AND eventDate < %@", sectionDate, sectionDate]];
    Item *item = filteredItems[indexPath.row];
    // Then fill out the cell using the item.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the amount of rows for each given section...
    NSDate *sectionDate = dates[indexPath.section];
    return [[items filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"eventDate >= %@ AND eventDate < %@", sectionDate, sectionDate]] count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // This is easy this is just the number of dates we originally found...
    return dates.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    // This is asking for the section with applies to the given title
    // 1) Get the date from the string
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:title];
    NSArray *filtered = [dates filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF >= %@ AND SELF < %@", date, date]];
    // The above array should only contain 1 date
    return [dates indexOfObject:filtered[0]];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // This is asking for the title for the given section
    NSDate *date = dates[section];
    return [formatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

NOTE: these data source methods are what you have to implement to organise objects in a table view by a certain attribute e.g. date. However, the code I've used to filter dates e.t.c is an example only and I haven't tested it so it may need some tweaking.

Comment: As I said at the bottom of my answer this is untested code that I have provided to give @Amy a starting point. ***is an example only and I haven't tested it so it may need some tweaking.*** Thanks for the -1 anyway.

Comment: the problem is that you assume a day being 24 hours long. this is wrong.